# why must post mothod be with a query string? how to remove the query string?

Tags: asp.net, api

```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action=RouteParameter.Optional, id = RouteParameter.Optional }  
  );      
===========================
    public class xxController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public int mul(int a)
        {
            return a * 10;
        }
    }
```

================================

```
(in API Help)
API                                Description
POST api/xx/mul?a={a}         No documentation available.

how can i make it from 
( POST api/xx/mul?a={a}) to ( POST api/xx/mul )?
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `int a` from `public int mul(int a)` or better add `[FromBody]` attribute to it.

`[FromBody] int a`  means you will send an integer in the request's body (not in query string).